# Is there a way to execute ActiveRecord queries in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Can I do something like a `Article.all` and `Tomato.all` at the same time, if both those tables were huge?

Comment: with threads you can

Comment: Did you consider using threads?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky and spickermann checking them right now. (This question is driven more of curiosity. Have you tried this use case for threads before? How was it like?)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people mentioned using threads. This is how you'd do it with them:

```
t1 = Thread.new { Article.all }
t2 = Thread.new { Tomato.all }
t1.join
t2.join
articles = t1.value
tomatoes = t2.value
```

Comment: I encounter connection leak years ago when using `Thead`. Is it not a issue now?

Comment: @khiavreoy You can wrap the calls in `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection` to help minigate leaks

Answer (score -1):

You could have each query parallelised by PostgreSQL, which might achieve your aim.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/parallel-query.html

Comment: I did not know about these, nice to have this in the potential toolkit when it comes to that point. But I'm looking right now to see if I can do this in Ruby.

Comment: Do you have a use case for this at the moment? I think the problem I'd see with it is working out what the value would be of retrieving two huge data sets into memory, and initialising a huge number of objects. It's not that it's invalid in some way to want to do this, just that use cases that are rare for some reason tend to not have a well documented and understood solution.

Comment: And I guess this also depends on your definition of "huge" :)

Comment: Ah, right. I would probably be paginating "huge" (let's say > 3 seconds to query + AR initializing the objects) queries anyway. I was just thinking if it was an optimization worth doing, let's say if they were from 2 different databases, or 2 different machines etc. Honestly, the use case is curiosity, just thinking if this is something that can be done in the future if the situation arises.

Comment: This describes how PostgreSQL internally executes ONE query in parallel and only under certain circumstances. The question was, how to execute MULTIPLE queries in parallel.

Comment: @mbuechmann Yes, I know those things. However, if the *aim* is to get the result of running two large queries faster, then this *can* achieve that aim. It depends what the critical performance path is – database query time, or processing the data in the client?

Comment: @DaryllSantos OK – a query that runs in 3 seconds, including AR initialising the results, is probably not a candidate for database parallel query. It's borderline, perhaps. I'll leave the answer here in case anyone is looking for this slightly different use case.

Comment: @DavidAldridge yup, thanks for the answer, I did not know about parallel queries in pg before, this could help also in non-AR or non-Ruby apps, just wanted to see what the approaches were just in case the queries took so long.

Comment: @DavidAldridge What I wanted to say is: This is not answering the question. Everything else is conjecture. All your points are valid, but this would rather merit a comment than an answer. But this is just IMHO.